# Tensorflow seq2seq

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

The api doc of tensorflow's tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.basic_rnn_seq2seq says:

```
(outputs, states) = basic_rnn_seq2seq(
    encoder_inputs,
    decoder_inputs,
    cell,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    scope=None
)
```

where, 
encoder_inputs: A list of 2D Tensors [batch_size x input_size]. 
decoder_inputs: A list of 2D Tensors [batch_size x input_size].

Question 1: Why are the sequence sizes (input_size) same for both the encoder_inputs and decoder_inputs. In my case, there are seq - to - seq mappings for unequal lengthts. For instance, "What are you doing" (length 4) -> "wie gehts (length 2)". Is it necessary to pad and make the sequences of equal lengths while using this tensorflow module?

Question 2: If I use the

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = 128)
```

The outputs come out to be of the size (batch_size x 128 [num of hidden units in lstm]) which really confuses me. Shouldn't it be equal to (batch_size x output_size)? What am I missing here? I am really confused how the decoder works here.